# Performing calculations on a set of values in a pandas data frame with respect to a certain attribute

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to find the year with the best average user rating. My approach is to find all the unique values in the Year column and then find the mean of all the values in the User Rating columns that correspond to those unique values.

I have managed to find unique occurrences in the Year column and have stored them in a list using:

```
import numpy as np

years = df.['Year'].unique()
years = np.sort(years)
print(years)

Output: [2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019]
```

I have to find mean value of User Ratings for each of these year values and then display which year has the best average User Rating. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show us your whole dataframe, or a sample of it?

Comment: Group by year and take the mean... `df.groupby('Year')['Rating'].mean()`